# Primefaces Datatable clear filter boolean value is setting to default(false)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primeface6.0, i have a datatable with data of 50 records and have paginator along with filter option, i am filtering data which does not exist in table and onclear boolean column is setting to false, below is the code.

```
<p:dataTable id="inventorytbl" value="#{inventorybean.inventoryList}"
                var="inventory" rows="15" paginator="true"
                paginatorPosition="bottom" pageLinks="5"
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" widgetVar="inventoryWidget"
                rowKey="#{inventory.code}"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <p:outputPanel>
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                onkeyup="PF('inventoryWidget').filter()"
                                onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false; }"
                                style="width:150px;float: right;margin-left: 5px;"
                                placeholder=" Enter keyword" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Material Name" style="width:23%"
                    sortBy="#{inventory.materialName}"
                    filterBy="#{inventory.materialName}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                    filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
                    <div title="#{inventory.materialName}">
                        #{inventory.materialName}</div>
                </p:column>
                // onfilter clearing button inside column getting disable(default to false)
                <p:column style="width: 10%;text-align: -webkit-center;"
                    headerText="Action" filterBy="#{inventory.activeFlag}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains"
                    filterStyle="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
                    <p:commandButton id="musterupdatelnk"
                        action="edit"


                        disabled="#{not inventory.activeFlag}" 
                        icon="fa fa-pencil-square-o"/>
                </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the built-in filter clear feature works properly, but I've ran into similar issue and have decided to create my own custom 'clear' button and placed it inside a column header.

```
            <p:column style="width: 16px;" exportable="false">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:commandLink id="clearFilterLink" onclick="PF('WidgetVar').clearFilters();"  styleClass="clear-filter-icon" />
                    <p:tooltip for="clearFilterLink" value="Clear Filters" trackMouse="true" position="right"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:rowToggler />
            </p:column>
```

This is just for your reference, but I think you can do something similar.  Maybe create a button somewhere on the page that clears the filter on click?

Comment: what is the 'built-in' clear feature? Isn't that `PF('WidgetVar').clearFilters();`?

Comment: The 'x' button within the filter input field.

Comment: I don't have that... Nor does the showcase. How do you get that? (Not saying you are wrong, just want to get things clear)

Comment: Oh I think it's not the 'clear' button.  It's more of uhm... 'x' button that clears the texts that you inputted within the inputText field.  I was confused, that was my bad.  Not sure how else to invoke the PF('...').clearFilters() method without creating a commandLink for it.  I think that was the problem I had earlier.  But this worked fine for me so I was just suggesting this.  Not really sure if this is problem he's having...

Comment: if you have the x in there you can simply add a jquery eventhandler to it and have that call the `PF('WidgetVar').clearFilters();`